# Dynamically generating validation attribute on input using interpolation

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

**Edit: This question is no longer relevant as of Angular `version: 1.3.0-beta.12` you can now parse ng-minlength and ng-maxlength dynamic values. See: https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/5319**

My problem is quite simple: I need to dynamically create input validation (ex. `ng-minlength`) using interpolation.

And doing that I am running into some issues specifically generating the validation attributes for `ng-minlength` and `ng-maxlength`. I assume this is due to them only taking constants?

Below you can see my code, the reason I am using a wrapper through outerForm is that I cannot dynamically generate the name attribute of input elements using interpolation, and that I have to wrap each set of repeated inputs in an `ngForm directive` and nest these in an outer form element.

So again, the problem lies in the attribute `ng-minlength="field.ValidationAttributes['data-val-length-min']"` not being properly set.

When I print the value directly using `{{field.ValidationAttributes['data-val-length-min']}}` the value appears correct.

Do I have to create a directive to parse my information, do I need to create my own min/max validation or am I simply running into a syntax error?

```
<form name="outerForm">
   <div ng-repeat="field in logEntry.StringValues">
      <ng-form name="innerForm">
         <input type="text" name="foo" ng-model="item.foo" ng-minlength="field.ValidationAttributes['data-val-length-min']" required/>
         <span ng-show="innerForm.foo.$error.required">required</span>
         <span ng-show="innerForm.foo.$error.minlength">to short</span>
      </ng-form>
   </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi you can use double {} to interpolate dynamic validation rules please see here: [http://jsbin.com/xayiro/1/](http://jsbin.com/xayiro/1/edit)

If you can post you field.ValidationAttributes model I can update jsbin.

HTML:

```
 <ng-form name="innerForm">
     <input type="text" name="foo" ng-model="item.foo" ng-minlength="{{validation.minlength}}" required/>
     <span ng-show="innerForm.foo.$error.required">required</span>
     <span ng-show="innerForm.foo.$error.minlength">to short</span>
  </ng-form>
```

JS:

```
 $scope.validation= {

    maxlength:20,
    minlength:3
  };
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for the solution. I just now found out that my problem has been fixed in the lastest version of Angular. https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/5319