# Angular Reactive Forms Dynamically Generating Validation Attribute on Input using Interpolation

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-reactive-forms, angular-validation

It seems to me that's exactly the same problem was raise in [Dynamically generating validation attribute on input using interpolation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24604893/dynamically-generating-validation-attribute-on-input-using-interpolation), however I'm looking for solution in `Angular`, not `AngularJS`.

In my Reactive Forms I'm using validators like so:

```
public contactForm: FormGroup = this.formBuilder.group({
  ...
  formControlDescription: [
    '',
    Validators.compose([
      Validators.maxLength(5000),
      Validators.minLength(30),
      Validators.required,
    ]),
  ],
  ...
});
```

On the `html` I'm hardcoding the number `5000` that way:

```
<mat-hint align="end">{{ contactForm.get('formControlDescription')!.value.length }} / 5000</mat-hint>
```

**Question:** is there a way to do it dynamically to access the `contactForm`'s `formControlDescription`'s `Validators.maxLength(5000)` in the `html`?

Comment: from where are you getting the 5000 value in first place?

Comment: In the `html`? It's hardcoded.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the error object from min/max validators as following:

```html
<mat-hint align="end">{{ contactForm.get('formControlDescription')?.errors.maxlength?.actualLength }} / {{ contactForm.get('formControlDescription')?.errors.maxlength?.requiredLength }} </mat-hint>
```

a bit cleaner version:

```html
<mat-hint align="end">    
  {{ contactForm.errors?.formControlDescription?.maxlength?.actualLength}} / 
  {{ contactForm.errors?.formControlDescription?.maxlength?.requiredLength}}
</mat-hint>
```

Official documentation on [maxLength Validator](https://angular.io/api/forms/Validators#maxlength)

**Update**

The values of angular validators will only become available to you when the validator is triggered and rendered Invalid.

E.g if you have `minLength(10)`, it will give you invalid input the moment it is touched and until the characters are or more than 10.
Same is for `maxLength(20)`, it will only available in the `errors` object once it's triggered i.e  user has type more than 20 characters.

This presents a problem if you intend to use the `actualLength` and `requiredLength` to show stats to user consistently as they will only appear when either `minLength` or `maxLength` is invalid.

As discussed, best approach for you will be to use a separate variable to set and show the required length. E.g:

```js
const validatorOptions = {
  maxLength: 5000,
  minLength: 5
}
```

then in your template use it:

```html
<mat-hint align="end">{{ contactForm.controls.formControlDescription?.value.length }} / {{validatorOptions.maxLength}}</mat-hint>
```

Comment: that's not me. I didn't downvote, actually I've upvoted. Will check it out soon, and if it works, I'll accept the answer :)

Comment: Thanks @DanielDanielecki, someone downvoted without mentioning any reason and I don't see what's wrong with the answer. Can you try my suggestion? comment if any issue arises with it

Comment: The `maxlength` didn't work out, but `minlength` work that way... [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55975546/11127383) shows a [demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-d9ktws?file=src/app/app.component.html) in which it works somehow.. Hmm, any idea? It looks like I've to [hardcode the value that way](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61393608/11127383), but I really want to do it like on that [demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-d9ktws?file=src/app/app.component.html).

Comment: @DanielDanielecki that's because errors become available to you only when validator is triggered. You have minLenght(50) so your input is invalid untill it reaches 50 charcters, it will disappear from errors above 50. But as you have maxLength(5000) so you will not have next error unless you reach 5000+ characters. 
I have demonstrated it here https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-8-reactive-form-b2xv2g?file=src/app/app.component.ts with minLenght(5) & maxLenght(10), hope it will clarify things for you

Comment: Also just a suggestion, having a separate variable isn't a bad thing, justify minimal & beautiful code with time spent on achieving it unless there is any other specific reason you don't want to use it. You can circumvent maxLength to give you value even before it's triggered but then you will have an invalid form even tho input will be between min & max and to circumvent that, even more code will be required

Comment: Got it now with the errors, I've create a public variables, which are exposed to the `html` as well as passed to `maxLenght` (and `minLength`) - like in the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61393608/11127383). Would you be able to update your answer with that information mentioned in these comments? I'd then accept it.

Comment: Have a look Daniel

Comment: Accepted :) Btw: I've created a separated variable for each of the validators, but that's just a small thing. Preferred to have express in a variable's `type` that's a `number`.

Comment: That's fine as well, just a matter of taste. i like to group similar data togther and type them with defined interfaces. Makes typehinting a bit easier in IDE. Glad your issue got solved, Good Luck :)